# How can I select a random folder from a list of folders?

Tags: vb.net, .net

i want to get a random directory from a specified directory, for example, the desktop.

im not sure how to do this, this and the only thing I'm having trouble with for my application

for example i have 5 different directories on the desktop called

Dir1
Dir2
Dir3, etc...

i would like to get Dir3, then maybe Dir1, after that maybe Dir3 again, and so on. i want to get a random directory from the desktop...dont really know how to explain it any better...

*A specified a directory* - a directory that i specify maybe in a text box for example. or a folder browser dialog

also i just want to get the path of the directory, i dont want to do anything to it.

If anyone could provide some information I would be greatly appreciative :D

thanks everyone!

Comment: Can you edit your question to be more specific? What does "a random directory from the desktop" (or any other specified directory, for that matter) mean? What does "get a directory" (in any location) mean - read, create, write...? It's not clear what you're trying to do, and that makes it difficult to give you an answer.

Comment: for example i have 5 different directories on the desktop called

Dir1
Dir2
Dir3, etc...

i would like to get Dir3, then maybe Dir1, after that maybe Dir3 again, and so on. i want to get a random directory from the desktop...dont really know how to explain it any better...

_A specified a directory_ - a directory that i specify maybe in a text box for example.

also i just want to get the path of the directory, i dont want to do anything to it. thanks :)

Comment: How about "How can I select a random folder from a list of folders?", or "a string from a random array of strings" (which would be a paths to the folders)? It doesn't matter that they're on the desktop; it just matters that you get a random folder from the list of several you have?

Comment: alright i'll change the title. you are right though, that is basically what i want to do. it doesnt necessarily have to be the desktop, i want to be able to pick which directory i get the random folder path from though, that is why i used the desktop for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of smells like homework to me. But I've got some time to kill. The function below takes a path as a string and returns a random subfolder as a string.

```
Public Function GetRandomSubFolder(path As String) As String
    ''//Static create a Random object so that we do not create a new one each time
    Static R As New Random()

    ''//Sanity check
    If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(path) Then Throw New System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException("path")

    ''//Get the subfolders as an array
    Dim SubFolders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path)

    ''//Sanity check
    If SubFolders.Count = 0 Then Throw New ApplicationException("Could not find any subfolders")


    ''//Get a random number. The second parameter is exclusive so (0,4) will always return 3 as a maximum
    Dim RandomIndex As Integer = R.Next(0, SubFolders.Count)

    ''//Return the path at that index
    Return SubFolders(RandomIndex)
End Function
```

Comment: I like this answer as you've used `Static` for the instance of `Random` (why c# doesn't have this feature I don't know) and you've done some pretty decent error handling. I would suggest though, that the `SubFolders.Count = 0` test should probably return `Nothing` rather than throw an exception as it's not really an exception circumstance. The first exception is exceptional though. Good answer nevertheless.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I definitely agree that the second exception should actually return `Nothing` in the real world. Unfortunately I've found that when I post code here like that we ultimately end up troubleshooting why "it doesn't work" and after a couple of posts we find that they're getting an NRE and then after a couple of more its because they're not sanitizing their input. So I gave up and my code here throw exceptions loud and clear explaining what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

That was fun!  :-D

Just change the `ParentFolder` to the folder you want to scan.

**RandomFolder.bat**

```
@Echo Off
Set ParentFolder=C:\Users\Me\Desktop
Set List=
For /F "tokens=* delims=" %%d In ('Dir /b /ad "%ParentFolder%"') Do Call :AddToList "%%d"
Set FolderCount=0
Call :CountFolders %List%
Set /a FolderIndex=%Random% %% %FolderCount%
Call :SelectRandomFolder %List%
Echo %RandomFolder%
Exit /B

:AddToList
Set List=%List% %1
Exit /B

:CountFolders
Shift
If "%~1"=="" Exit /B
Set /a FolderCount=%FolderCount% + 1
Goto :CountFolders

:SelectRandomFolder
Set RandomFolder=%~1
If %FolderIndex%==0 Exit /B
Set /a FolderIndex=%FolderIndex% - 1
Shift
Goto :SelectRandomFolder
```

Comment: thats good for batch and i code in batch so i will remember that but this is for VB :P

Comment: LOL!  I've been answering too many batch questions today.  :-D